# Running native google map app inside of my app

Tags: android, ios, webview

Is it possible to run the google maps native app inside of my app, or does it have to be launched separately? I want to give the appearance of only one app running, mine. If the first answer is yes, what sort of control or method could I look up and use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot embed the Google Maps *app* into your app. You can embed native Google Maps into your app via [the Play Services SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/).

Comment: What I really want from google maps is the voice directions. So if I merely built my own directions code for my app using their api, I'm not sure that I would be able to do the voice directions part.

Comment: @user192632: More importantly, that might violate their terms of service.

Comment: Makes sense. Just wanted to make sure I knew for sure before I tell someone no. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to integrate the Google Maps SDK into your app. Here's a link to that SDK:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start

I would recommend installing via CocoaPods. Here's a tutorial on how to get started with CocoaPods:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift

Once you've installed the Google Maps SDK via CocoaPods, you'll need to get an API key and integrate it into your app:

> To use the Google Maps SDK for iOS, you must register your app project on the Google Developers Console and get a Google API key which you can add to your app. Note: There are various types of API keys. You need an iOS key, not a browser key.

If you're using the standard API, you need an iOS key set up in a project of your choice.

Here's more information on that:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/get-api-key

Comment: It looks like this would involve me building my own custom directions app using their api, rather than just using their app itself. I was hoping to do the latter.